# Problema para volver al menú en calculadora

Tags: java

estoy teniendo unos problemas para volver al menú y quisiera saber si me pueden iluminar jajaj, ya intente de todo, tengo entendido que una buena forma para volver al mismo es con un do while, ya acomode y todo pero al momento de "acomodar" donde te pida el valor de que si queres o no volver al menú da error. Sinceramente hace un par de horas estoy tratando y no encuentro solución.

Pongo el codigo completo asi me pueden ayudar un poco mas facilmente, es mi primer proyecto en Java y se me ocurrio hacer una calculadora para practica general.

Gracias!

```
package arg.com.Calculadora;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Valores {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sg = new Scanner(System.in);
        Metodos colores = new Metodos(), operacion = new Metodos();
        MetodosSecundarios opSecundaria = new MetodosSecundarios(), consola = new MetodosSecundarios();
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println(colores.colorCeleste + "**************Menu**************");
                System.out.println(colores.reiniciarColor + "Ingresa 1 para realizar una suma");
                System.out.println(colores.colorCeleste + "********************************");
                System.out.print(colores.colorVerde + "Numero: " + colores.reiniciarColor);
                int cases = sg.nextInt();
                switch (cases) {
                    case 1:
                        try {
                            consola.limpiar();
                            System.out.print("Ingresa el primer numero para la operacion suma: ");
                            double nur1 = sg.nextDouble();
                            System.out.print("Ingresa el segundo numero para la operacion suma: ");
                            double nur2 = sg.nextDouble();
                            System.out.print("Desea ingresar otro numero? - Y/N: ");
                            sg.nextLine(); //Salto de linea en el escaner (internamente) asi puede tomar string
                            String pregunta1 = sg.nextLine();
                            if (pregunta1.equals("Y") || (pregunta1.equals("y"))) {
                                System.out.print("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
                                double nur3 = sg.nextDouble();
                                System.out.println("La suma es: " + colores.colorRojo + opSecundaria.getResultadoSumaSecundario(nur1, nur2, nur3));
                            } else
                                System.out.println("La suma es: " + colores.colorRojo + operacion.getResultadoSuma(nur1, nur2));
                        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                            consola.limpiar();
                            System.out.println("Solo numeros enteros!");
                            System.out.println("Codigo de error: " + colores.colorRojo + "InputMismatchException");
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        consola.limpiar();
                        System.out.println("Opcion no valida. Verifique el numero ingresado");
                        System.out.println("Numeros admitidos: 1 - 11");
                        System.out.println("Numero ingresado: " + colores.colorRojo + cases);
                        break;
                } //Cierra el switch
            } //Cierra el try que va en conjunto con el catch debajo (Detallado en el mismo)
            catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                consola.limpiar();
                System.out.println("Solo numeros enteros!");
                System.out.println("Codigo de error: " + colores.colorRojo + "InputMismatchException");
            } //Cierre del catch que detecta la excepcion InputMismatchException en el menu
            String preguntamenu = sg.nextLine();
        }while (preguntamenu.equals("Si"));
    } //Cierra metodo main
} //Cierra la clase arg.com.Calculadora.Valores
```

3 lineas arriba esta el while, supongo esta bien acomodado, ya que al terminar algún case te lleva directamente al final, y mi duda radica en donde acomodar para que te pida ingresar valor.

Avísenme cualquier duda, gracias!

Proyecto en github así se puede visualizar mejor (avísenme si lo coloque correctamente por favor, primera vez que lo utilizo)

https://github.com/SkyGhostK/CalculadoraPrimerProyecto.git

Comment: Sugiero que no incluyas todo el código, sino un [mcve].

Comment: Ya. Elimine gran parte del mismo. Gracias!